# Celery instead of Async views with asyncio in django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, python-asyncio

I am new to django! (So basically i am seeking suggestions for this approach).

In my project i had so many views and each view had at least 1 database i/o and as all my views are synchronous i find this is not efficient way, So to make it efficient:

1. I can use asyn views with await asyncio on Database update operations (create, update, delete records), but read operations should be done synchronously as it should be delivered to frontend.
2. I can use celery tasks to do Database update operations and do DB read operations normally.

which approach is better/efficient and are they both logically same for the above use case?

Comment: Do neither unless you absolutely need to. For instance, if all writes were through a work queue, then your user would never know if their write actually succeeded!

Comment: Also, please elaborate on "i find this is not efficient way" – what's not efficient? How did you measure that?

Comment: ooh wow i didn't think of that (db update success/fail).Thankyou soo much.
ok so not efficient means like resource utilization and no multiprocessing.

Comment: @AKX So I should use asyncio only to views having more than 1 DB i/o to make efficient use of async behaviour right?

Comment: No, you should only look at asyncio when you know your performance isn't enough otherwise. Surely so far you've profiled your app and figured out the bottlenecks?

Comment: No, I'm still in development process like adding new features and while developing i got this doubt. (like i thought like implementing my work as optimal as possible while developing only, now i find that only after complete development, we need to go for optimizations). Thankyou.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256145/discussion-between-varun-k-21-and-akx).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.